# How do I pass data from the client-side to my nodejs server using socketio?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Using socketio on the client side and nodejs with socketio on the server side, how would I go about passing data from the client side to the server? Would I use an emit function with socketio on the client side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Client side or server side you simply emit events and handle events.

client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
```

server side:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! So if I wanted to use nodejs with redis sub pub system and wanted to pass the channels I want the current client to join, I would use the emit to pass this information from the client to the nodejs script?